# xPath and importXML busy

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I created a year ago a code which allows to retrieve information via importXML and Xpath, but since a few weeks it does not work anymore, and I can not find the problem.

I would like to retrieve for example on the page the number of employees : https://www.societe.com/societe/patisserie-thomas-753249192.html (info in French : Tranche d’effectif)

For example, i would like to retrieve the info: 6 to 9 employees by making a regular expression on the word employee (salariés), which allows to then recover the workforce. And same for the other information (Adresse postale, SIREN, etc...)

I was able to make an XPath code `//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/a/@href` to get info in a table, but that's not working.

Here is the way in which i recuperate the info. CompagnieName is just a example, can be change with any compagnie. I think that the XPath line is not correct, but i cannot find what to change, problem with div or other...

[image]

Other picture :

[image]

And after the info should appear in the following form.

[image]

If you had a solution or changes that i can made, that would be of great help to me.

Thank a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it:

[image]

First: There was a wrong structure of searching url.
Then I tried xpath: //div/div[@class='Card frame']/a/@href
This lists all urls that are under class 'Card frame'
Also I think you need to add + in each query url where you use more than one word.
That's why I add this in resultat (B4)
[image]

I am not sure if this is what you looked for but it returns all the urls of places in result.

I added my work as a new Sheet in your file.

Comment: Thank you very much, the search function is working perfectly now. And now i can use the search form again, i must just change some info in the Spreadsheet. Really thanks a lot @Krzysztof Dołęgowski

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to work while you don't share your file.

You asked about number of employees for your example page:
You can import this using:

```
=importxml("https://www.societe.com/societe/patisserie-thomas-753249192.html";"//div[@id='trancheeff-histo-description']")
```

It returns 5 to 9

You can find right id in Chrome developer tools (F12).

Comment: Thank Krzysztof Dołęgowski, I will test tomorrow thanks, i will keep you posted if it works.

Comment: i have test your code is great, but I can not find the good ID for the xPath search form.Actually I use  `//*[@id="input_search"]/div[1]/a/@href`, but I have no answer. For the file you can see here : [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yLFTVTnC_YwqO1zGX2BQhncJyQZuiOgyTROPo1wBhcg/edit?usp=sharing Thanks for your help.